# Access numeric NSDictionary key in NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary, nspredicate, predicate

I'm trying to write a predicate to check a specific value in a dictionary I have set up.

This dictionary has string versions of "0", "1", and "2" as keys which I would like to access.

The predicate I would like to write is:

$player.currencyDictionaries.0.earned > 1000

The problem is that .0 is not allowed.  Assuming I cannot easily change how the dictionary stores values (this is in older versions and I'd like to use the same predicate on all versions as it is hosted on a server) is there any way to access the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, you can do this:

```
$player.currencyDictionaries[0].earned > 1000
```

(You might need to do `['0']` to guarantee that the passed value is a string and not a number)

Note that this syntax (`[0]`) *only* works in predicate format strings.  It does not work with key paths.

This syntax is defined under the "[Index Expression](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pBNF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001796-217950)" section of the Predicate BNF.

---

**EDIT**

Actually, this won't work, and here's why:

The string `"$player.currencyDictionaries[0].earned"` will be read and turned into an `NSExpression` of type `NSKeyPathExpression`. This means, when it's evaluated, it's going to basically take that string and run it through the receiver's `-valueForKeyPath:` method.  As I mentioned above, the bracket syntax doesn't work with key paths, and thus this will produce the incorrect answer.

However, since you know the `currencyDictionaries` returns an `NSDictionary`, and since `NSDictionary` [overrides the `-valueForKey:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-BBCIBCDJ), you can turn the `[0]` bit into a key path, by turning it into a literal string:

```
$player.currencyDictionaries.'0'.earned
```

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767374/hyphen-in-nsdictionary-key

I have tested and verified that writing my predicate like this works:

$player.currencyDictionaries.'0'.earned > 1000

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for my specific predicate, I get the exception: Caught: -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: list)

Comment: I would answer my own question but I cannot due to my rating.

Comment: Even with the edited ['0'] I'm still getting that exception.  Using dot syntax and '0' without the [] works.

Comment: @M2tM ah, it's likely because it's part of a key path expression, and the `[]` syntax doesn't work with key paths.  I'll update my answer.